# Apple Automator, Shell Script and batch files - video subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, workflow, batch-processing, automator, video-subtitles

I'm making a Workflow to burn SRT to MP4. It's is working but I want it to go to all files of a folder and didn't find a way even with "Dispense Items Incrementally".

I have the SRT and the MP4 in the same folder, so I need the workflow to filter the results to only try the script with the MP4 files and maybe this is the problem for "Dispense Items".

Because the subtitled file goes to the same directory, the filter also excludes files named with "_SUB".

The image is below if someone has an idea... I'm open to other methods of doing this. I just need to go to a folder with 44 MP4 files (and .SRT with the same name) and batch encode the videos with subtitles.

Thank you,
Luiz

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKMWf.jpg)

Comment: What is wrong with the "Run Shell Script" as shown in the image? Looks like it should do what you want.

Comment: It works fine for ONE file (MP4 + SRT). My problem is in making it run over a folder full of MP4 and SRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal, navigate to the directory containing the files, and run:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf "subtitles=${f%.*}.srt" -c:a copy "${f%.*}_srt.mp4"; done
```

Comment: Thank you. Very elegant solution. I was over-complicating it.